# Force layout zoom resets on first tick of dragging or zomming

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to implement a force layout graph using d3 v4, and I'm having a problem with the default zooming and panning behaviours of the graph on the first tick of these functions. 
Since it's a somewhat large graph (~700 nodes) I'm using the `transform(translate())` function of d3 to set the initial position and zooming after declaring the `svg` element as so:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .call(d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.05,2])
        .on("zoom", zoomed))
        .append("g"), width = +svg.attr("width"), height = +svg.attr("height");
var initialScale = 0.1,
        zoomWidth = (svg.attr("width")-initialScale*svg.attr("width"))/2,
        zoomHeight = (svg.attr("height")-initialScale*svg.attr("height")/2);
```

After that, I declare the initial position and scale of the element:

`svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + (zoomWidth+400) + "," + (zoomHeight+325) + ")scale(" + initialScale + ")");`

For the zooming, panning and tick functions, I'm using the code from [this Mike Bostock example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

```
function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x ;
    d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}
function zoomed() {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    // Manually offsets the zoom to compensate for the initial position. Should get fixed asap or the position variables made global.
    //svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.transform.x + 400) + "," + (d3.event.transform.y + 325) + ")scale(" +  d3.event.transform.k + ")");
}
function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    gnodes
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
        });
}
```

(As you can see from the comment, I even tried manually setting those initial points as modifiers to the `zoomed()` function, but that didn't solve anything).

The problem is that the initial `0.1` zoom that is set after declaring the svg is being reset whenever you try to drag or pan over the visualization for the first time (after that, it works correctly until the page is reloaded). It seems to default to some zooming scale that I don't seem to be able to control properly so that it starts zooming from the `initialScale` value that is set globally.

You can watch a gif of the behaviour [on this gfycat](https://gfycat.com/HeartyUnconsciousFlee) I made.

I've also read [the answer to this question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197442/d3js-how-do-i-clear-the-zoom-scale-set-by-the-d3-zoom-event), which seems to be related to my problem, but I can't implement a proper solution (my very little experience with d3 yet might be the cause for this, I'm sure). Since I'm declaring the zoom object directly on the svg declaration, I don't know if I should be declaring the zoom object elsewhere and then manually attaching it to the svg, or how I should do so (again, very little experience).

I've been fighting this for a couple of days and haven't been able to solve this even though the answer might be very simple, so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be manually setting the `scale` like you are doing with:

```
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + (zoomWidth+400) + "," + (zoomHeight+325) + ")scale(" + initialScale + ")");
```

Instead, create a [transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom-transforms) and operate on that using `.call` [zoom.transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_transform):

```
  // initial setup
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.05, 2])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("svg").call(zoom), //<-- apply zoom to svg
    g = svg.append("g"), //<-- g for append elements, this is what you are zooming
    width = 960,
    height = 600;

  var transform = d3.zoomIdentity //<-- create your transform with your initialScale
    .translate(width / 6, height / 6)
    .scale(0.5);

  svg.call(zoom.transform, transform); //<-- apply your initial transform, this will fire you zoomed event
```

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

The reason for separating out the `svg` and the `g` is that the svg element here is the event receiver.  It is the element to which the zoom event handlers are bound (in most `d3` examples, you'll see a `rect` element being used for this).  The `g` on the other hand, is the container element that's being zoomed.

Here's a full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }
  
  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.05, 2])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("svg").call(zoom),
    g = svg.append("g"),
    width = 960,
    height = 600;
    
  var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(width / 6, height / 6)
    .scale(0.5);

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  svg.call(zoom.transform, transform);

  var graph = {"nodes":[{"id":"Myriel","group":1},{"id":"Napoleon","group":1},{"id":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},{"id":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},{"id":"CountessdeLo","group":1},{"id":"Geborand","group":1},{"id":"Champtercier","group":1},{"id":"Cravatte","group":1},{"id":"Count","group":1},{"id":"OldMan","group":1},{"id":"Labarre","group":2},{"id":"Valjean","group":2},{"id":"Marguerite","group":3},{"id":"Mme.deR","group":2},{"id":"Isabeau","group":2},{"id":"Gervais","group":2},{"id":"Tholomyes","group":3},{"id":"Listolier","group":3},{"id":"Fameuil","group":3},{"id":"Blacheville","group":3},{"id":"Favourite","group":3},{"id":"Dahlia","group":3},{"id":"Zephine","group":3},{"id":"Fantine","group":3},{"id":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},{"id":"Thenardier","group":4},{"id":"Cosette","group":5},{"id":"Javert","group":4},{"id":"Fauchelevent","group":0},{"id":"Bamatabois","group":2},{"id":"Perpetue","group":3},{"id":"Simplice","group":2},{"id":"Scaufflaire","group":2},{"id":"Woman1","group":2},{"id":"Judge","group":2},{"id":"Champmathieu","group":2},{"id":"Brevet","group":2},{"id":"Chenildieu","group":2},{"id":"Cochepaille","group":2},{"id":"Pontmercy","group":4},{"id":"Boulatruelle","group":6},{"id":"Eponine","group":4},{"id":"Anzelma","group":4},{"id":"Woman2","group":5},{"id":"MotherInnocent","group":0},{"id":"Gribier","group":0},{"id":"Jondrette","group":7},{"id":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},{"id":"Gavroche","group":8},{"id":"Gillenormand","group":5},{"id":"Magnon","group":5},{"id":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},{"id":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},{"id":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},{"id":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},{"id":"Marius","group":8},{"id":"BaronessT","group":5},{"id":"Mabeuf","group":8},{"id":"Enjolras","group":8},{"id":"Combeferre","group":8},{"id":"Prouvaire","group":8},{"id":"Feuilly","group":8},{"id":"Courfeyrac","group":8},{"id":"Bahorel","group":8},{"id":"Bossuet","group":8},{"id":"Joly","group":8},{"id":"Grantaire","group":8},{"id":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},{"id":"Gueulemer","group":4},{"id":"Babet","group":4},{"id":"Claquesous","group":4},{"id":"Montparnasse","group":4},{"id":"Toussaint","group":5},{"id":"Child1","group":10},{"id":"Child2","group":10},{"id":"Brujon","group":4},{"id":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}],"links":[{"source":"Napoleon","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Baptistine","target":"Myriel","value":8},{"source":"Mme.Magloire","target":"Myriel","value":10},{"source":"Mme.Magloire","target":"Mlle.Baptistine","value":6},{"source":"CountessdeLo","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Geborand","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Champtercier","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Cravatte","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Count","target":"Myriel","value":2},{"source":"OldMan","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Labarre","value":1},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Mme.Magloire","value":3},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Mlle.Baptistine","value":3},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Myriel","value":5},{"source":"Marguerite","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Mme.deR","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Isabeau","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gervais","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Listolier","target":"Tholomyes","value":4},{"source":"Fameuil","target":"Tholomyes","value":4},{"source":"Fameuil","target":"Listolier","value":4},{"source":"Blacheville","target":"Tholomyes","value":4},{"source":"Blacheville","target":"Listolier","value":4},{"source":"Blacheville","target":"Fameuil","value":4},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Blacheville","value":4},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Blacheville","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Favourite","value":5},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Blacheville","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Favourite","value":4},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Dahlia","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Blacheville","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Favourite","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Dahlia","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Zephine","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Marguerite","value":2},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Valjean","value":9},{"source":"Mme.Thenardier","target":"Fantine","value":2},{"source":"Mme.Thenardier","target":"Valjean","value":7},{"source":"Thenardier","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":13},{"source":"Thenardier","target":"Fantine","value":1},{"source":"Thenardier","target":"Valjean","value":12},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":4},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Valjean","value":31},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Tholomyes","value":1},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Javert","target":"Valjean","value":17},{"source":"Javert","target":"Fantine","value":5},{"source":"Javert","target":"Thenardier","value":5},{"source":"Javert","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Javert","target":"Cosette","value":1},{"source":"Fauchelevent","target":"Valjean","value":8},{"source":"Fauchelevent","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Bamatabois","target":"Fantine","value":1},{"source":"Bamatabois","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Bamatabois","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Perpetue","target":"Fantine","value":1},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Perpetue","value":2},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Fantine","value":2},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Scaufflaire","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Woman1","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Woman1","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Judge","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Judge","target":"Bamatabois","value":2},{"source":"Champmathieu","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Champmathieu","target":"Judge","value":3},{"source":"Champmathieu","target":"Bamatabois","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Judge","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Champmathieu","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Bamatabois","value":1},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Judge","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Champmathieu","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Brevet","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Bamatabois","value":1},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Judge","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Champmathieu","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Brevet","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Chenildieu","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Bamatabois","value":1},{"source":"Pontmercy","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Boulatruelle","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Eponine","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":2},{"source":"Eponine","target":"Thenardier","value":3},{"source":"Anzelma","target":"Eponine","value":2},{"source":"Anzelma","target":"Thenardier","value":2},{"source":"Anzelma","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Woman2","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Woman2","target":"Cosette","value":1},{"source":"Woman2","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"MotherInnocent","target":"Fauchelevent","value":3},{"source":"MotherInnocent","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gribier","target":"Fauchelevent","value":2},{"source":"Mme.Burgon","target":"Jondrette","value":1},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Mme.Burgon","value":2},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gillenormand","target":"Cosette","value":3},{"source":"Gillenormand","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Magnon","target":"Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Magnon","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Gillenormand","target":"Gillenormand","value":9},{"source":"Mlle.Gillenormand","target":"Cosette","value":2},{"source":"Mlle.Gillenormand","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Mme.Pontmercy","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Pontmercy","target":"Pontmercy","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Vaubois","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Lt.Gillenormand","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":2},{"source":"Lt.Gillenormand","target":"Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Lt.Gillenormand","target":"Cosette","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":6},{"source":"Marius","target":"Gillenormand","value":12},{"source":"Marius","target":"Pontmercy","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Lt.Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Cosette","value":21},{"source":"Marius","target":"Valjean","value":19},{"source":"Marius","target":"Tholomyes","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Thenardier","value":2},{"source":"Marius","target":"Eponine","value":5},{"source":"Marius","target":"Gavroche","value":4},{"source":"BaronessT","target":"Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"BaronessT","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Mabeuf","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Mabeuf","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Mabeuf","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Marius","value":7},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Gavroche","value":7},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Javert","value":6},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Valjean","value":4},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Enjolras","value":15},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Marius","value":5},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Gavroche","value":6},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Mabeuf","value":2},{"source":"Prouvaire","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Prouvaire","target":"Enjolras","value":4},{"source":"Prouvaire","target":"Combeferre","value":2},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Gavroche","value":2},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Enjolras","value":6},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Combeferre","value":5},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Marius","value":9},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Enjolras","value":17},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Combeferre","value":13},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Gavroche","value":7},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Mabeuf","value":2},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Feuilly","value":6},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Prouvaire","value":3},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Combeferre","value":5},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Gavroche","value":5},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Courfeyrac","value":6},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Mabeuf","value":2},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Enjolras","value":4},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Feuilly","value":3},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Marius","value":5},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Courfeyrac","value":12},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Gavroche","value":5},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Bahorel","value":4},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Enjolras","value":10},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Feuilly","value":6},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Combeferre","value":9},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Joly","target":"Bahorel","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Bossuet","value":7},{"source":"Joly","target":"Gavroche","value":3},{"source":"Joly","target":"Courfeyrac","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Enjolras","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Feuilly","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Joly","target":"Combeferre","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Joly","target":"Marius","value":2},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Bossuet","value":3},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Enjolras","value":3},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Combeferre","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Courfeyrac","value":2},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Joly","value":2},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Bahorel","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Feuilly","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Prouvaire","value":1},{"source":"MotherPlutarch","target":"Mabeuf","value":3},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Thenardier","value":5},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Thenardier","value":6},{"source":"Babet","target":"Gueulemer","value":6},{"source":"Babet","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Javert","value":2},{"source":"Babet","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Thenardier","value":4},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Babet","value":4},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Gueulemer","value":4},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Enjolras","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Babet","value":2},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Gueulemer","value":2},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Claquesous","value":2},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Toussaint","target":"Cosette","value":2},{"source":"Toussaint","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Toussaint","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Child1","target":"Gavroche","value":2},{"source":"Child2","target":"Gavroche","value":2},{"source":"Child2","target":"Child1","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Babet","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Gueulemer","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Thenardier","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Claquesous","value":1},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Montparnasse","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Bossuet","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Joly","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Grantaire","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Bahorel","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Courfeyrac","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Enjolras","value":1}]};
  
  var link = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

  var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.group);
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    // Manually offsets the zoom to compensate for the initial position. Should get fixed asap or the position variables made global.
    //svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.transform.x + 400) + "," + (d3.event.transform.y + 325) + ")scale(" +  d3.event.transform.k + ")");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked beautifully. However, one thing struck me as interesting. It was not enough to do only the `svg.call(zoom.transform, transform)` after setting up the `zoom` object. It was actually important to *separate* the `svg` and `g` object declarations, and have the `zoom.transform` function applied *over the `svg`* and then have the `zoomed()` function get applied only over the `g` element. Not sure why that works that way, but I'll leave the comment in case anyone goes through the same process (or wants to be kind enough to explain the behaviour). Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @juanjocerero, see updated answer.  I should have called out the reason for that better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and effort to update the answer. I now understand how the system works way better than when I started writing this question.