# Element is coming to position 0,0 on applying D3.zoom (D3 v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I have few SVG elements on my webpage. Initially I am applying D3.zoom() on every element like this:

```
d3.selectAll("svg")
       .call(d3.zoom()
           .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
           .on("zoom", function () {
           d3.selectAll("g")
               .attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
       }));
```

This is working fine, its zooming all my elements together.

But after this I want one element to translate to another position so I am doing this:

```
d3.select("#myElement")
        .attr("transform", "translate(125,45)");
```

Doing this translates the element to desired position. But after this when I am zooming #myElement comes back to 0,0 and then zooms as it was zooming previously

I want #myElement to zoom at its changed place.

I read that I have to reset my zoom point. If this is correct how can I do this or is there any other way to do this?

here is the D3 documentation https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoomTransform

**EDIT 1**

As commented by Mark, I changed the code a little

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
   .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
   .on("zoom", zoomed);

var zoomAll = function () {
    d3.selectAll("svg")
        .call(zoom);
};

function zoomed() {
    d3.selectAll("g")
        .attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(125, 45);

d3.select("#myElement")
        .call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

this is also resulting in same problem.

Comment: Here's a similar question, [I answered some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688256/force-layout-zoom-resets-on-first-tick-of-dragging-or-zomming/39689877#39689877).  You are manually setting a `transform` but **not** telling the zoom behavior about it.

Comment: Hi [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark), Thanks for the comment. I changed my code a little bit as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688256/force-layout-zoom-resets-on-first-tick-of-dragging-or-zomming/39689877#39689877) answer but its also doing the same thing. I already have <svg> and <g> elements in my html page. Is there any solution for this

Comment: Hi @Mark I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5bL9ya2/) for this. Can the group #myElement be translated to the specific position.

Comment: I'm really curious what your use case is for this.  Consider this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5bL9ya2/1/), where I've hacked it in so that the second `svg` knows about the starting translate.  You'll notice on zoom the first `svg` "jumps" to the second.  The drag event is only happening on the first and you are assigned the translate of the first to the second.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I got a workaround. wrapped the elements which I want to translate with another <g> and translated this <g>.