# D3 Radial Dendrogram jumps to top left

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm using React and D3 to create a Radial dendrogram. It has drag and zoom functionality. It jumps to the top left corner whenever I move the map.

I've created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j20ry8r74w) to demonstrate the problem. Click on the diagram after it loads to see the jump to the top left.

I posed a similar question previously, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738778/cannot-translate-initial-d3-zoomidentity-without-jerkiness-on-zoom), with a slightly different D3 map, which had the same issue. However, my attempts to apply the solution there have failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call the `zoom` function with the desired transform:

```
svg.call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

Here is the forked CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjn98n7l5q